# How many parameters can pass to a docker entrypoint via cli

Tags: docker

Is there any limitation in number of params or cli length for passing parameters to entrypoint of a docker container?

I've tried to look it up in [docker run documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) without success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need pass that env via cli. Set them in entrypoint file is better...

Comment: I have no idea, but I have some with big parameters, specially for java servers, some cases we are using entrypoint as file to handle this and inside you have sh or bash

Comment: No, I'm not talking about env, but parameters behind the entrypoint. I want to know what's the limit for entrypoint parameters, not that I can use a file. That's what I'm doing but I doesn't look pretty. Thanks anyway